# What is the *.cf7 file extension?

Tags: file-format

At work we have been given a .cf7 file from a client and been expected to know how to access it's contents. We suspect it is some sort of database or accounting records file, most probably propriety, as it was contained in a folder called "books and records".

Has anyone dealt with .cf7 files before? Does anyone know how to use one such file? Opening it in a text editor reveals it is of a binary nature. Any [pointers](http://xkcd.com/138/) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What program(s) are (or previously were) used to open the file? At least *that* information should be available (from the client) and may lead to the answer or at least more clues.

Comment: Run `hexdump -C` on it.  Maybe there are clues inside the file itself.

Comment: Another good idea is to try using the `file` utility on a *NIX box. This usually has a good idea about most formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a product called Cashflow Manager. It also uses the .cf7 extension.

Comment: We were never able to figure it out (requirements changed and it wasn't a priority), but I'm gonna take your word for it and accept your answer :D